# Android: BottomNavigationView set custom colored icon on selected tab

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am using BottomNavigationView and i want to change tab icon (make it gradient colored) when it selected.

problem: when I set gradient icon in OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, it doesn't work, the color changes.

I tried to change default coloring from xml, setting app:itemIconTint, but here i can give only color selector, where I couldn't use gradient

So is it possible to set custom colored custom icon in BottomNavigationView selected tab?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a package color in res folder. Inside it create a XML file with a selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorLightGrey"  />
</selector>
```

Here you can set the color of the icon when they are selected or not.

You can use the XML file inside your BottomNavigationView like this :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_state_list"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_state_list"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"/>
```

nav_item_state list is the XML file above

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't need flat color, I need gradient

Comment: Okay it's possible to do it but you need more code you need to create a custom class and extend TabLayout, check on web they are a lot of exemple, with this custom class you can inflate each item with custom view then it's easy to apply a gradient on it